# Where is the fork database?

Tags: chainbase

I am just reading source code of EOS but I am not clear with **fork databases**.

I do not know exactly where it is (on RAM or on disk). I also would like to have a look at the exact code. Which files are relevant?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The still reversible blocks are stored in `blocks/reversible`.

The reversible *state* is kept in RAM, and keeps track of *inserts*, *deletes*, and *updates* in their `undo` / `redo` forms, so they can be applied and unapplied when a change of longest chain occurs. If you're looking at the source, check references to `chainbase` instead of fork.  Check the `squash`, `commit` methods, and around here: https://github.com/EOSIO/chainbase/blob/master/src/chainbase.cpp#L217

Comment: Thank @abourget, I read it. You said: The reversible state is kept in RAM so when it becomes to irreversible state so where is it? It will be stored on disk, if it true why use must pay fee for RAM?